# Basic Algebra Inequality Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is there a formal proof that $x<2 \iff -x>-2$, or is this just a matter of convention?

Comment: It is one of the axioms of an ordered field.

Comment: By definition $\,a > b\iff a-b > 0.\,$ So $\ 2> x \iff 2-x > 0 \iff -x > -2 \quad $

Answer (score 5):

$x<2$

$0<2-x$      (add $-x$ to both sides of the inequality)

$-2<-x$      (add $-2$ to both sides of the inequality)

Answer (score 3):

Well if $x < 2$, then $(x - 2) < 0$.  But if the number $(x - 2)$ negative, multiplying it by $-1$ gives a positive number.  So we get:

$-(x - 2) > 0$

$-x + 2 > 0$

$- x > - 2$

Answer (score 2):

If

$a < b$

then adding $-a - b$ to both sides of the inequality yields

$-b < -a$

which can be written in the equivalent form

$-a > -b$

In your problem, $a = x$ and $b = 2$.